# Why does OAuth 2 have Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant?

Tags: oauth

Why would anyone use OAuth 2 with this kind of grant? I mean, if the client already has the name and password of the Resource Owner, why not just authenticate as the Resource Owner using whatever authentication vehicle is used by the Resource Server?

I do not understand the rationale here. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the spec mentions, the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant is for migration purposes and applicable only in scenario's where (typically) the Client and the Authorization Server are controlled by the same party, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3:

> The resource owner password credentials (i.e., username and password)
> can be used directly as an authorization grant to obtain an access
> token.  The credentials should only be used when there is a high
> degree of trust between the resource owner and the client (e.g., the
> client is part of the device operating system or a highly privileged
> application), and when other authorization grant types are not
> available (such as an authorization code).

It allows for utilizing a standard token and protocol on the leg between Client and Resource server (e.g. OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token), whilst using a "to-be-deprecated" way of getting a token between Client and Authorization Server. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.7:

> The resource owner password credentials grant type is often used for
> legacy or migration reasons.  It reduces the overall risk of storing
> usernames and passwords by the client but does not eliminate the need
> to expose highly privileged credentials to the client.
>
> This grant type carries a higher risk than other grant types
> because    it maintains the password anti-pattern this protocol seeks
> to avoid.    The client could abuse the password, or the password
> could    unintentionally be disclosed to an attacker (e.g., via log
> files or    other records kept by the client).
>
> Additionally, because the resource owner does not have control over
> the authorization process (the resource owner's involvement ends when
> it hands over its credentials to the client), the client can obtain
> access tokens with a broader scope than desired by the resource
> owner.  The authorization server should consider the scope and
> lifetime of access tokens issued via this grant type.
>
> The authorization server and client SHOULD minimize use of this
> grant    type and utilize other grant types whenever possible.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on this grant? If I'm creating a backend api, don't I need at least one application with this type of grant, to allow the user to authenticate somewhere? If the user never inputs user and password anywhere, how is it supposed to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

I will provide another point of view.

OAuth 2.0 is a great protocol for common web applications. Some applications, however, use much stronger authentication / authorization mechanism. For these cases, it makes sense to allow token establishment using a strong method. An example of such application can be a banking API - it can use classic OAuth 2.0 flow on web (using bank's website) and strong data signatures using protocols like PowerAuth 2.0 (I am an author of this solution) for native mobile or desktop apps.